# Relative $K$-theory, definition

Tags: vector-bundles, k-theory, topological-k-theory

On [pg125](https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/jeber_02/skripten/mainfile.pdf) on proving that that the concordance classes quotiented by the acyclic ones froms a group, there is a lemma:

> **Lemma 8.4.5** Let $(E,F,f)$ and $(E,F,g)$ be two $K$-cycles on $(X,Y)$. Assume that 
>       $$f^*g +g^*f \ge 0 \text{ or } fg^*+gf^*  \ge  0$$
>       holds over $Y$. Then these two cycles are homotopic.

I do not understand this statement, where does the equality come from? At best I know locally we can regard the bundle morphism $f$ as a map $f:U \rightarrow GL_n(\Bbb C)$.

What is $f^*$? Is it the conjugate?

Comment: The only reasonable explanation is that $f^*$ is the *adjoint bundle morphism* (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint). This is defined fiberwise by taking adjoints of linear maps (which requires the we have inner products on the vector bundles). Then $\ge 0$ means  *positive semidefinite*.